# Blessing for softening hearts?

Tags: blessing

I am not certain if such a thing exists but does anyone know a prayer or blessing for the softening of the heart of parents. I am going through a lot in life and need their support but sadly they are very closed. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great first question! Nice to have you learning here with us, @MichaelRe

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Michael and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specific blessing, but I once had a personal problem and I asked Rav Moshe Lazerus if it's ok to pray to Hashem for someone's heart to change and he said yes, Hashem does do that on occasion, such as with rulers, e.g. King Pharaoh. This was many years ago so I don't remember any more details but it stuck with me that he didn't even hesitate to say yes so feel free to pour your heart out on this to Hashem and expect blessings.

Hatzlacha.

Comment: Thank you, Rabbi. I appreciate that. Yes, when I was writing this the story of Pesach played in my head. I appreciate the support and the opportunity to learn.

Comment: @MichaelRe it is truly our priviledge to have you here to learn with us. Looking forward to your future engagements